# Ember Models Table - JSON records

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-model

Has anyone successfully loaded a JSON file externally via an ajax call in [Ember Models Table](http://onechiporenko.github.io/ember-models-table/)?

I was hoping [this example](http://onechiporenko.github.io/ember-models-table/#/examples/server-table) would work, but there is no associated coded with it.  Currently it seems it only works, if you grab your data from your ember store.  But maybe there is a way to inject the records another way?

Perhaps passing it to 'model' somehow?:

```
{{models-table
          data=model
          columns=columns}}
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem? You can pass any data to `data`. Probably just fetch your data in your `model` hook and then pass them to the component. Probably you should try to load and display your data without `models-table` first, and if you solved that problem try to use the component.

Comment: Yes, I was overcomplicating it... will be posting my solution shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply doing a Ember.$.getJSON in the model.

```
model: function(params) {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('***YOUR_URL_HERE***').then((data) => {
        return this.store.push({
            data: data
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask yourself if you want to use ember-data or not.

If you want to use ember-data you probably should override your adapter, and implement `findAll` or `findQuery`.

if you don't want to use ember-data probably you can just do something like this in your `model` hook:

```
model() {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('http://example.com/mydata');    
}
```